# Why are junctions used in thermocouples?

Tags: solid-state-physics, thermoelectricity

Thermocouples work on the principle of the Seebeck effect. In the simplest one-dimensional form, the voltage appearing between two points on a conducting solid having a temperature difference of $\Delta T$ is given by

$$\Delta V=S\Delta T$$

where $S$ is the Seebeck coefficient. If we have a junction between two conductors, one kept at a temperature difference $\Delta T$ with respect to the other, then the voltage difference appearing at the junction is

$$\Delta V=S_{ab}\Delta T$$
where $S_{ab}$ is difference between the Seebeck coefficients of both conductors.

In a thermocouple, we want $\Delta V$ to be large enough for a given $\Delta T$. So, **why are junctions preferred? Is it easier to make a junction with a large value of $S_{ab}$ than it is to find a metal with large $S$?**

*Here is what I found so far:*

I think it is not that. The choice of junctions is made due to the fact that Seebeck coefficient changes with temperature. In the application of thermocouple, it is easier to have a relatively steady value of the *difference* between two Seebeck coefficients compared to keeping track with the change in the Seebeck coefficient.

Comment: If there is no junction, then there is no way to compare the voltage differences, and thus no way to extract the temperature information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong. We use junctions because otherwise you would get $Saa$, or $Sa-Sa$, which is just 0. In other words, you would get no voltage reading giving information about the temperature of the considered point/junction.

The Seebeck effect taking place from your reference temperature up to the junction would be canceled by the one going from the junction up to your reference temperature.